# Data passed to other component is deleted when screen is changed in React Native navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to add items from FlatList to favorites and then send those to my Favorite component with props. I'm using React Navigation BottomTabNavigation to change screens. The problem is, when I change screens, no data reaches the Favorite component. I test that by setting up a console.log in the Favorite component. So when I click add to favorite checkbox, the console.log prints that the items have been added to the list. But as soon as I press the tab button to go to the Favorites component, console.log prints that the array is empty.

Here is the code

```
//Home component

function Home() {
 const [favorites, setFavorite] = useState({ currFav: [], checked: [] });
  ...
  
  // The data from an API is processed and send to the FlatList.
  //rest of the code for checking the items and saving them to the favorites works nicely.

  return (
   <View>
    // here Flatlist and checkbox etc
    ...
    // Below I pass the favorites and the function to remove favorites to the Favorite 
    // component
    <Favorites data={favorites.currFav} handleFavorite={handleFavorite} /> 
   </View>


}

function Favorites({ data }) {

 const [favoritesList, setFavoriteList] = useState(data); // I passed the data as the 
 // initial value of the state. 
 //console.log(props) If I print all the props, I also see the React Navigation props as 
 // well. 
 
 // I tried to save the the data to the favoriteList like this as well but still didn't work
 // useEffect(() => { 
 // setFavorite(data);
 // }, []);

 console.log("favorites in Favorite Component is: ", data);
 // Console prints the items when I add them from Home component. 
 // But when I press the Favorite bottom in the TabNavigation, interestingly enough, nothing 
 // is printed to the console!  

 ...// Rest of the code such return the Views etc. 
 }
```

I have all the imports and exports correctly. I know there is {navigation} prop passed to all the components by the ReactNavigation and I can send parameters to it. But in their documentation, they say I shouldn't pass large data like mine. I think I'm not saving the data to the favoriteList state correctly. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It's ***actually*** an anti-pattern in React to store passed props in local state. Are you rendering more than one `Favorites` component in your app? It seems like you have one on the home page, and another *different* one on a favorites page.

Comment: Hi. I see. The favorites are first selected from Home component in a FlatList. Original data is very large and it's coming from an API.  Then I want to list only those that are selected in another component "Favorites". I think the issue is that when I switch to the Favorite component, the data sent from Home doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Correct, when `Home` unmounts, its local state is potentially garbage collected. You can [Lift State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to a common ancestor to both and pass down, or use the React Context API, or some app state management like redux, to do the same.

Comment: Right! Thank you for taking the time to look at this.